# Select bool, from start time, and set length

Tags: mysql, time

Title improvements are accepted. English isn't my first language.

What I need is basically a way of returning a boolean (1 or 0), depending on if a match is still on going.

I have following columns:

```
dato date()
start time()
```

And I need the boolean returned, 1/0, if the day is the same, and if the current time is within `start` and 110 minutes forward. I haven't been able to figure this out all day.

Don't mind column names - These aren't the real ones, just ignore reserved keywords.

Comment: could u please post the table and some data in www.sqlfiddle.com along with sample data and the expected output to ur question ?

Comment: @Frederik: in the summertime some clubs here at home organize special midnight cups. In this case your restriction of the same day wouldn't be valid. But if you think of a tournament that takes place at another continent, i.e. in Brazil, you've got the same.

Comment: You're very right. I'm still looking for a way of redoing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timestampdiff` to calculate the difference of time on the day.
I assume that, when you said, `if the day is same` it is current date.

```
select
  timestampdiff( minute, concat( dato, ' ', start ), now() ) >= 110
```

If it is not the current date, then replace `now()` in the above solution with other valid `datetime` value and then run.

**Example**:

```
mysql> set @dato = curdate();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @start := curtime() - interval 120 minute;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select
    ->       timestampdiff( minute,
    ->                      concat( @dato, ' ', @start ),
    ->                      now()
    ->       ) >= 110 as 'diff > 110';
+------------+
| diff > 110 |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

---

**Followup**:

`timestampdiff` takes least date first and the later date next. If you want to find a positive difference on future dates too, you have to use least and greatest of the column dates with current time.

```
SELECT 
   @dt := concat( gamedate, ' ', starttime )
 , @nw := now()
 , @diff := 
     timestampdiff( 
       minute, 
       least( @dt, @nw ),
       greatest( @dt, @nw )
     )
 , @diff >= 110 as 'diff > 110 min ?'
FROM games
```

**Example** on [***MySQL 5.5.32 Fiddle***](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/806928/1)

Comment: Returns 0, every time. I'll get you a fiddle. 2 sec.

Comment: Yes. And you have the answer at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3599/1 with your data.

Comment: well, `timestampdiff` takes least date first and the later date next. If you want to find a positive difference on future dates too, you have to use `least` and `greatest` of the column dates with current time.